# finding indices that would sort numpy column returns zeros

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get the indices that would sort each column of an array using the function `argsort`.  However, it keeps simply returning zeros instead of the true indices.  For example:

```
x = np.matrix([[5, 2, 6], [3, 4, 1]])
print(x)

print(x[:,0])
print(x[:,1])
print(x[:,2])

print(x[:,0].argsort())
print(x[:,1].argsort())
print(x[:,2].argsort())
```

I am expecting this to return three arrays. `[1 0]`, `[0 1]` and `[1 0]` denoting the indices of each column if it were sorted, however, instead I get three arrays that all contain zeros.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Indexing a `matrix` with a slice *always* returns another **2-d** `matrix`. (This behavior is not the same as for a regular numpy array.) See, for example, the output of `x[:,0]`:

```
In [133]: x[:,0]
Out[133]: 
matrix([[5],
        [3]])
```

`x[:,0]` is a `matrix` with shape (2, 1).
To argsort the first (and only) column of that matrix, you have to tell argsort to use the first axis:

```
In [135]: x[:,0].argsort(axis=0)
Out[135]: 
matrix([[1],
        [0]])
```

The default (`axis=-1`) is to use the last axis, and since the rows in that matrix have length 1, the result when `axis` is not given is a column of zeros.

---

By the way, you can do all the columns at once:

```
In [138]: x
Out[138]: 
matrix([[5, 2, 6],
        [3, 4, 1]])

In [139]: x.argsort(axis=0)
Out[139]: 
matrix([[1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0]])
```